# GROUP BY query displays only one row associated with date in html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I tried a query to show items of same date in my table with different rows but date should be displayed only once. Something like this.

```
Date: 15-09-2015
      ItemId:1  quantity:6 size:XL
      ItemId:1  quantity:4 size:Small
      ItemId:2  quantity:6 size:XL
Date: 16-09-2015
      ItemId:3  quantity:9 size:XL
      ItemId:1  quantity:4 size:Small
      ItemId:2  quantity:6 size:XL
```

I tried the following query. It just returns me only one row for each date.

```
SELECT orders.date, order_detail.quantity, order_detail.price, order_detail.color, order_detail.size, customers.name, products.product_name, products.product_image FROM order_detail JOIN orders ON orders.serial=order_detail.orderid JOIN customers ON customers.serial=orders.customerid JOIN products ON products.productid=order_detail.productid WHERE customers.email='abc@yahoo.com' GROUP BY orders.date ORDER BY orders.date
```

Any suggestions please. How can i display like this in my html table.

Comment: Can you show what output you want exactly? Instead of showing Row 1, Row 2 ....

Comment: @TheGuest I have edited my question have a look please

Comment: So, Date: 15-09-2015 comes in first row? and the first row has only one column and rows 2, 3 and 4 has 3 columns and again row 5 has only one column? Like that you want?

Comment: @TheGuest I have multiple transactions on same date in my db. But i want to display on my html table something like i have mentioned in my question. The table structure should be like this

Comment: Now I understand. Why don't you select the rows order by date and in your code you can write some logic to do this. Did you think about it?

Comment: @i have done this but it shows date with all items

Answer (score 0):

Group by looks for an aggregate function i.e. sum('field_name'). You will need to get the distinct values for the order.date then subquery (not sure the parentheses are in the right spot).

```
SELECT DISTINCT orders.date, (SELECT order_detail.quantity, order_detail.price, order_detail.color, order_detail.size, customers.name, products.product_name, products.product_image FROM order_detail JOIN orders ON orders.serial=order_detail.orderid JOIN customers ON customers.serial=orders.customerid JOIN products ON products.productid=order_detail.productid WHERE customers.email='abc@yahoo.com') GROUP BY orders.date ORDER BY orders.date
```

Comment: This shows me date with all items . I just want to show the date once in my table for all the items purchased on same date.

Comment: it gives the following error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY orders.date ORDER BY orders.date
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1`